# how to write an if condition case in stored procedure

Tags: sql, stored-procedures

i have an table  where i am   passing  5 paramter

```
table name=" image"
parameter
@imageID,
@imageName,
@imageDirectory,
@imageResource,
```

from  the  front end [from page  that is  from  textbox control]  if they  didnot send any values to  stored  procedue then  i  should   do an simple  Query
condition1:

```
 select  * From image
```

condition 2: 
if they send  any value  to   these  above  parameter
 then collect  those vlaues and  retrive  result based  on the parameted sent

condition 3:
 here they might  send  values  to any of the  of the  parameter 
 in that  condition   select  values  for that parameter . for the  parameter  which they have not send  values  we  can   send 'null' or ' '

so  based on that retrive the result

so how write an Stored procedure  for  such an condition. handling  all the  three  condition

anyhelp  would  be  really great 
  thank you

Comment: Better to list your columns explicitly rather than by * though.

Answer (score 5):

Try something along these lines:

```
SELECT * FROM IMAGE i
WHERE 1=1 
AND (@ImageID IS NULL OR i.ImageId = @ImageID )
AND (@ImageName IS NULL OR i.ImageName = @ImageName )
AND (@ImageDirectory IS NULL OR i.ImageDirectory = @ImageDirectory)
AND (@ImageResource IS NULL OR i.ImageResource = @ImageResource)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the `IsNull`(transact-SQL specific)  or `Coalesce` (SQL-92 standard) function, as in:

```
 Select * From Table
 Where imageId = Coalesce(@ImageId, imageId)
    And imageName = Coalesce(@imageName,imageName)
    etc.
```